# How to stop debugging .net assemblies after uninstalling Net Reflector

Tags: debugging, redgate, .net-reflector

I installed the Net Reflector trial to accomplish a specific task, but now even after I've uninstalled it the debugger still goes into .net assembly code that I would rather it skip over.

How do I get it to return to the previous behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the Redgate uninstaller did its job, there's only one setting that could affect this.  Tools + Options, Debugging, General.  Untick the "Enable .NET Framework source stepping" option.  You probably prefer "Enable Just My Code" ticked.

If that doesn't solve it then you'll need help from Redgate to get your machine in working order again.

Comment: That's probably it... and I should have guessed that.